# typo3: add a record in a folder with html and javascript code

Tags: typo3

I don't know anything about Typo3. I was assigned the role of maintaining a web site created with Typo3.

I have a dashboard created with a online tool, I want to embed it. I have a folder with lot of record. How can i add a record with this code in it ?

```
<div 
    class="infogram-embed" 
    data-id="..." 
    data-type="interactive" 
    data-title="...">
</div>
<script>!function(e,n,i,s){var d="InfogramEmbeds";var o=e.getElementsByTagName(n)[0];if(window[d]&&window[d].initialized)window[d].process&&window[d].process();else if(!e.getElementById(i)){var r=e.createElement(n);r.async=1,r.id=i,r.src=s,o.parentNode.insertBefore(r,o)}}(document,"script","infogram-async","https://infogram.com/js/dist/embed-loader-min.js");</script>
```

[image]

When i create a new "Nouvelles" (=News):
I try to add the code in code source but It doesn't accept it.

[image]

[image]

when we click on *Title* we go to a new page.

When I click on *List View > Page*, I have a template called **ext+**. In ext+ > *Inclusion tab*. (Gabarit = template)

[image]

**tt_news is key for the extension News 7.6.1**

Answer (score 1):

Due to security reasons you cannot enter javascript into regular content elements / richtext/wysiwyg fields.

Are you usung a custom "nouvelles" content element? In that case you could add a custom "raw text" field. Then you edit your template of the output of that content element, and emit the field without escaping (i.e. in fluid templates you would use <f:format.raw>). That way you can enter javascript into that field and it will be emitted.

Another (better) way would be to create a distinct content element where your javascript is already part of the template. Then you could define an attribute like "enable javascript for XXX" and emit that javascript in your templage, when enabled. You could then add specific placeholders/attributes in your javascript as custom element properties (like "title", "widtb", "number of dashboard elements",...).

Comment: I did not create the project, I suppose it is an addition since when I create a new folder I do not have the "Nouvelle" content element. 
In your first solution, how can I edit the template ? In the *template* section, I only have create suggestions.

Comment: Oh - ok. In that case you will definitely need to get down to the programming/source of the extension. This is nothing an editor can do for themself, this is an developer/integrator task. Are you interested in developing TYPO3 extensions, then I can give some pointers to the proper places: TCA field controls, fluid templates, ext_tables.sql database extension. If you can show me the extension you're using for the fields above, I can offer to add that new "raw html" field to it for you.

Comment: Hello, where can i view the extension of Folder ?

Comment: Your screenshot is heavily edited, so lets polish my 8-ball I assume you're seeing the default List view of a SysFolder called "Folder" and the record type is called "Nouvelles" (news, supposedly?) But I believe this is not EXT:news here? You would have to check your typo3conf/ext/ directory or the Extension Manager to see which extensions are installed, and if any sound like "News" or "Nouvelles".

Comment: Hello, I go to *Admin tool -> Extensions* , they are lot of extension ^^. I think the extension **News** (line 11) correspond to what we are looking for, the description is *website news with front page teasers and article handling inside*. https://vigorous-output-288.notion.site/Extension-Typo3-d525b6daf51f4182af8ce4b3042d7a70 . I edited my first post to add more context and show how the rendering is done.

Comment: Oh, god :) You are using TYPO3 7.6 - this has gone out of maintenance in 2018! You need to upgrade that site, there are several security issues with it probably. Also, I am not able to instruct you how to add the extension of fields eaily with such an old version. If this is a commercial site, you should look for a professional to help you with the upgrade, and also add the feature you're needing now. For a personal/private page, if you're willing to do some "homework", you can learn TYPO3 from the Documentation and Videos, but this will be a learning curve...

Comment: Hello, ok ^^.  Can i add a html file with the embeded code in file system then I link the file with the "Nouvelles" ? In "Nouvelles" i can choose  in **Type**: Nouvelles, Article or External URL.  When i choose **External URL** I can link with a file in **file system** .

Comment: Yes, you could do that with an external link and a custom HTML document. You could also write custom javascript that does the loading/injection, based on data-attributes or specific links inside your News. You could add a placeholder in your news like "[SHOW-THIS]". Then your custom javascript could check the DOM for this placeholder, replace it with your active javascript, and embed that. But if you can work with a complete external link, that will be the easiest way for you.

Comment: Hello, I create a page (new_page), in *general > type >* i set *html >* then in *code html* part I add the code. The page doesn't print the content. But In the tree of my project i have lot of page at another level. When i move new_page in another page, the code work and display the dashboard. In this another page, the javascript code is allow but not in Page (Page element where the Folder is contained). How can I allow javascript now that I have a html page element ?

Comment: You can't (easily) - and shouldn't. It's a security matter to embed javascript. Extension fields sanitize content differently than page content elements. You would have to fork/patch/edit the tt_news extension. But again... you should focus on upgrading your TYPO3 instance instead, patching such an old version won't really be helpful and easy much.

Comment: Hello, thank for your help.